# Function $f:\kappa\to\alpha$ with small fibers where $\alpha\in\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Is it consistent in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, cardinals $\alpha, \beta\in\kappa$ and a function $f:\kappa\to \alpha$ such that for each $x\in\alpha$ there is an injective map $i:f^{-1}(\{x\})\to \beta$?

Comment: I think in ZFC one can write $\kappa=|\Gamma_f|=|\coprod_{x\in \alpha}f^{-1}(\{x\})|\leq\alpha\beta=\mathrm{max}(\alpha,\beta)<\kappa$? Which point fails in ZF?

Comment: @Qfwfq How do you prove $|\coprod_{x\in \alpha}f^{-1}(\{x\})|\leq\alpha\beta$ in $\mathrm{ZF}$ if you don't have a choice function $x \mapsto i_x \colon f^{-1}(\{x\}) \to \beta$?

Comment: Do $\alpha,\beta,\kappa$ have to be alephs? I guess so, because you are treating them as sets?

Comment: @Qfwfq You're welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is consistent.

Consider a (transitive) model of $\mathrm{ZF}$ in which $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality. Fix a strictly increasing, cofinal sequence $(\xi_n \mid n < \omega)$ in $\omega_1$. Consider
$$
f \colon \omega_1 \to \omega, x \mapsto \min \{n < \omega \mid x < \xi_n \}.
$$
$f^{-1}(\{n\})$ is bounded in $\omega_1$ for all $n \in \omega$. Hence there is an injection
$$
i \colon f^{-1}(\{n\}) \to \omega.
$$